# Decoupling functionality in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how I can decouple some React components -- specifically modals -- so that the components which will open the modals don't need to know how they are opened.

For example, in jQuery I could do something like:

```
var $modal = $(".modal");
var modals = {};

/* Gets a modal dialog
*/
function _get_modal(modal) {
  if(modals[modal] === undefined) {
    modals[modal] = $(".modal-dialog[data-modal=" + modal + "]");
  }

  return modals[modal];
}

/* Shows the modal page dimmer and the modal dialog
*/
function show_modal(modal) {
  var $m = _get_modal(modal);

  $modal.show();
  $m.show();

  return $m;
}

// Later in a click event listener somewhere...
show_modal("MyModal");
```

If I wanted to do this same thing in React it seems like I would need to pass down a function from my parent component to all of the children and the children's children so that they know how to trigger the modal.

**Ideally, I'd like to abstract what I'm getting at to be able to implement a Command pattern.**

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at react-modal. It encapsulate already the modal. https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal. And even if you are not using it you might get an idea how to encapsulate things in react. One note: Command pattern is an OOP pattern, react has a functional approach. Investigate how to handle things more in the functional way. HTH

Comment: `react-modal` doesn't help. In their [example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal#examples) `App` needs to provide the functionality for opening the modal and that functionality is passed down to the children with an `onClick` prop. It's still coupled.

Comment: all modal function ist separated in a component and yes sure at some point it needs to be called but I do not see an issue here.  And since everything is a function in React there is nothing that should stop you in writing a function that returns a <Modal /> but remember it's React which follows the reactive mindset (which is different from jquery). Maybe you should also post your React code and we'll have a look.